# Chrome alarms not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, google-chrome-extension

I've created a Chrome alarm using:

```
chrome.alarms.create('start', { when: Date.now() + msToWait });
```

Now, the alarm should have gone off, but instead what I do when I inspect with:

```
chrome.alarms.getAll(function(list) { console.log(list); });
```

is this:

```
{
    name: 'start',
    scheduledTime: 1460287800001
}
```

but currently it's past that time (`new Date(1460287800001)` === `Sun Apr 10 2016 13:30:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`), as right now it's around `Sun Apr 10 2016 13:41:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`.

I'm receiving the messages with:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    console.log('Triggered');
    // some other action
});
```

but that's never triggered.

Is this a bug?

Chrome version is 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit).

---

Between the time that I've set the alarm and when it should have gone off, hours have passed (I've set it at least 8 hours before the scheduled time), and the computer (Mac) has gone into sleep mode in the meanwhile, but when the alarm was supposed to go off, I was using the computer just fine.

---

Just to check that my clock is not broken, the following:

```
new Date();
```

results in:

```
Sun Apr 10 2016 13:49:19 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

---

I should also say that the same exact code works when triggered in 10/20 minutes distance from the moment it's set.

Comment: Possibly related: https://crbug.com/471524

Comment: whats the relation with browserAction.onClicked?

Comment: @ZigMandel Woops. Miscopied. Fixed.